# When socket.io emits to 'login', TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working on a chat app using angular 4 and socket.io.
Here is my code

```
export class UserService {
socket;


// determines if a user is logged in or not
loggedIn: '';

constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.socket = io('http://localhost:8890');
    this.socket.on('login', function (result) {
        if (result) {
            this.loggedIn = true;
            this.router.navigate(['/profile']);
        } else {
            this.loggedIn = false;
        }
        localStorage.setItem('loggedIn', this.loggedIn);
        console.log(result);
    });
}}
```

So whenever socket.io emits to 'login', I get this error on my console
**ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined**

I changed the code and initialised `router` out of the constructor:

```
export class UserService {
socket;


// determines if a user is logged in or not
loggedIn: '';
router: Router;

constructor() {
    this.socket = io('http://localhost:8890');
    this.socket.on('login', function (result) {
        if (result) {
            this.loggedIn = true;
            this.router.navigate(['/profile']);
        } else {
            this.loggedIn = false;
        }
        localStorage.setItem('loggedIn', this.loggedIn);
        console.log(result);
    });
}}
```

I still get the same error.

How can I access `router` so that I can redirect to another page if `result` is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are losing the context of your `this` variable, which is why `this.router` is undefined. Use arrow syntax to keep the context:

```
this.socket.on('login', (result) => { // <--- here
    if (result) {
        this.loggedIn = true;
        this.router.navigate(['/profile']);
    } else {
        this.loggedIn = false;
    }
    localStorage.setItem('loggedIn', this.loggedIn);
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Can I know why we are losing the context of `router` variable without using arrow syntax?

Comment: Its the whole point of arrow functions. Arrow functions maintain the lexical scope of the "outerscope" while anonymous or named functions using the `function` keyword create a new lexical scope. That's why `const` and `let` are so important to ES6, they respect a "block" scope (`{}`) whereas `var` only respected a `function` scope. The accepted answer here does a good job explaining it in detail - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch

Comment: @Brian. But we  can use either the `bind()` method. Correct?

Comment: Thanks @RameshRajendran. `this.loggedIn = true;` still works inside the socketio function. I do not still understand why

Comment: @CashDogg  because `this.loggedIn` is a variable but ` this.router` is an object. So  your problem is  `this.router` object is null or undefined then how could be you call `navigate` function? like `null.naviaget()`(it should be throw an error like **Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined** reason of no references are there for `this.router` object .  You should try what @Fento told.

Comment: @RameshRajendran yes, using `function () {}.bind(this)` is exactly what arrow functions are doing under the hood.

Comment: @Brian So what is the difference between them? Any idea?

Comment: Thanks very much @Fenton

Comment: @RameshRajendran really? I just explained it and left a link explaining the differences. Why would you call `.bind()` everywhere when there's a much cleaner short hand? It's just syntactical sugar. You don't have to use it but it's considered a best practice these days.